# Angular 15 - Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the Angular 15 project and apply @angular/fire but it's not working properly as below:

**ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).**

**AppModule** config here

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// region firebase
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideStorage, getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { FIREBASE_OPTIONS } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { FirebaseRealtimeDataService } from './firebase-realtime-database.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseV2)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
  ],
  providers: [
    FirebaseRealtimeDataService,
    { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebaseV2 }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is an example to testing for Angular 15.

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseRealtimeDataService } from './firebase-realtime-database.service';
import { onValue } from "@firebase/database";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private firebaseRealtimeDataService: FirebaseRealtimeDataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const listFileRef = this.firebaseRealtimeDataService.getListFileRef('wedding');
    onValue(listFileRef, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      console.log(data);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    }, {
      onlyOnce: true
    });
  }
}
```

It was failed at getDatabase().

**FirebaseRealtimeDataService**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, push, update, remove, query, limitToLast } from "firebase/database";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirebaseRealtimeDataService {

  getListFileRef(basePath: string) {
    const db = getDatabase();
    return ref(db, basePath);
  }

}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-ex-firebase",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I find out the root cause. In the FirebaseRealtimeDataService.ts, we need to import more Firestore libraries to fix this issue.

`export class FirebaseRealtimeDataService {
  private readonly fireStore = inject(Firestore);
....
}`